# jquery customized html5 video not working in ipod

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css, html5-video

I've developed one JQuery API for HTML5 Video skins and controls. It works perfectly in Chrome, FF & Opera.

But its not working in iPod and mobile devices. I know that we can't customize the skin for iPod. In the mean time, I just the video to be played in that.

Please help me out. The link is: [www.iseofirm.net/appthateam/vel/static2/](http://www.iseofirm.net/appthateam/vel/static2/)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: My bad, I'm tired. Forget what I wrote.

Comment: Flash is auto fall back...
In default, html5 player will only be played...
for browsers like ie8 and below, flash will be played...

My question is to play html5 player in iPod